# Change Label content dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

First of, I apologize if this sounds stupid, but I'm very new to WPF. I'm doing a timer, and I want to change the Label to display the remaining time. I've tried changing the Content directly and by data binding to a property. When I do the former, the program simply crashes; as for the latter I don't really understand how it works, I've looked around and all I could do was take some hints from snippets of code around the web, but it's not working and since I don't know what I'm doing, I don't know where I'm going wrong either.

The code: I'm putting many things on the MainWindow class, it's not great code, but it's good enough for my purpose. When I tried changing the content directly I did it by setting a delegate called by my timer class, when called does this:

```
private void updateTimerLabel()
{
  lblTimer.Content = TimeToGo;
}
```

where TimeToGo is the following property:

```
public String TimeToGo
{ 
   get { return task.TimeToGo.Hours + ":" + 
                task.TimeToGo.Minutes + ":" + task.TimeToGo.Seconds; }            
}
```

As for the binding attempt I set the following Dependency Property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeToGoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "TimeToGo", typeof(String), typeof(MainWindow));
```

and did this in the XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="ToDoTimer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ToDoTimer" Height="210" Width="348" 
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">    


    <Grid Width="326" Height="180">
        <Label Content="{Binding TimeToGoProperty}"  Height="63" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,104" Name="lblTimer" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Width="218" FontFamily="Courier New" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have without any binding (tested and it's works):

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
TimeSpan timeToGo = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    this.timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

    this.endDate = DateTime.Now.Add(timeToGo);

    this.timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lblTimer.Content = this.ToStringTimeSpan(this.endDate - DateTime.Now);

    if (this.endDate == DateTime.Now)
    {
        this.timer.Stop();
    }
}

string ToStringTimeSpan(TimeSpan time)
{
    return String.Format("{0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
}
```

Comment: I did something similar, as you can see. 
However, whenever the following function is called, the program terminates.

private void updateTimerLabel(TimeSpan timeToGo)
        {
            lblTimer.Content = String.Format("{0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", timeToGo.Hours, timeToGo.Minutes, timeToGo.Seconds);
        }

Comment: However I tried your code on an empty project and it works fine. I'll probably use it for now. I still wonder what my problem is...

Comment: So the problem was the Timer as written below.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using DispatcherTimer but not Timer?

Comment: No, I wasn't using DispatcherTimer, I was using the System.Threading.Timer. I've redone my code using the DispatcherTimer, it all works now. What's the difference?

Comment: Timer will use the main thread, DispatcherTimer will use the UIThread.